# Can I remove the anaconda while leaving the conda (Ubuntu)?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

Can I remove the **anaconda** *without removing* the **conda** on Ubuntu?

Definitely, I want all my projects and environments will remain.

I have seen instructions on how to remove anaconda, but *I don't understand, the Conda & environments & projects will remain or not*?

Comment: What do you mean by removing `anaconda`? Do you jsut want to get rid of the preinstalled packages?

Comment: Yes, I want reduce the space by removing unused things. I manage conda packages from command line now for my environments. And it seems I can remove a lot of unused  things. Or I am not right?

Comment: Do you have packages in the base environment that you actually use or do you have everything in seperate environments?

Comment: I have all my things in environments.